# How can ı make responsive my carousel and images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I want to make an image slider that will cover fifty percent of the homepage. but somehow I can't make these photos sensitive. I want my carousel to shrink as it resizes. I just found some solutions with Jquery on the internet, but I want vanilla javascript or pure css & scss solution. How can I make my slider and photos responsive?
For demo: https://codepen.io/BerkayAkgurgen/pen/qBqMxeo

```
   <main>
        <div class="slider-container">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="./img/batman-banner.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img class="deneme2" src="./img/lord-of-the-ring.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="./img/avengers.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="./img/batman.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

```
 img {
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

main {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 500px;
}

.slider {
    width: 100vw;
    max-height: 500px;
}

.slider-img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you mean by 50% of the home page. Is this always 50% width of the viewport or is it different on a portrait orientated device?

Comment: For example, above 1200px it will cover half of the screen such as 50vw, and it will automatically resize itself below it.

Comment: Does this just mean that at any viewport size it will be 50vw wide? I haven’t understood what a 1200px breakpoint means in this case.